# Assign different interfaces to the same object

Tags: typescript, object, interface

I have a Typescript project in which I want to pass the same object between several functions with a different interface

These are the interfaces:

```
export interface TestModel {
  fileName:string,
  year:number,
  country:string
}
export interface Test2Model {
  fileName:string,
  year:number
}
```

This is the first function that generates the object and calls the second function passing it the generated object:

```
function test1() {
  let fileData:TestModel = {
    fileName:'fileName',
    year:2022,
    country:'Spain'
  }

  test2(fileData)  
}

test1();
```

This is the second function:

```
function test2(fileData:Test2Model) {
  console.log(fileData)
}
```

This is what I get in the second function:

```
{fileName: "fileName", year: 2022, country: "Spain"}
```

This is what I want to receive:

```
{fileName: "fileName", year: 2022}
```

**My problem**: is it possible to automatically generate the second object adapted to the Test2Model interface without creating a new object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the property, the type can't change the object. Use delete keyword like

```
delete fileData.country

//then pass it to test2 function
```